# KL divergence between binomial distribution and Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, closed-form, information-theory

Let $$P(X=k) = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\ Q(Y=k) = \frac{\lambda^k\exp(-\lambda)}{k!}$$ I'm trying to find $D_\text{KL}(P||Q)$. I obtained $$D_\text{KL}(P||Q) = \sum_{k}P(k)\ln(\frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\ln(\frac{{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{\frac{\lambda^k\exp(-\lambda)}{k!}}) = \\ np\ln(p/\lambda) - np\ln(1-p)+n\ln(1-p) + \lambda +\ln(n!) - \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\ln((n-k)!)$$ Is there any closed-form expression for the last summation? $$F(n,p) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\ln((n-k)!)$$

Comment: An approximation using Stirling can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784064

Comment: @VezenBU Thanks. I'm looking for a closed-form expression.

Comment: I think since $F(n, p) = \sum_{j=1}^n \ln j \sum_{k=0}^{n-j} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ which involves partial sums of binomial coefficients without closed-form formula, this might be still an open problem.